# Erro ao inserir dados no banco, EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando inserir dados no banco, mas tenho um erro ao fazer o `saveChanges();` depois de fazer varias vezes o `context.add()`, já aconteceu depois de 500, 2200 e 5500 vezes.

Erro:

**A transação associada à conexão atual foi concluída, mas não foi descartada. A transação deve ser descartada antes do uso da conexão para executar as instruções SQL.**

Tenho uma função que insere os dados:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)))
{
    Contexto context = null;
    try
    {
        context = new Contexto();
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        int count = 0;            
        for (int i = 0; i < textoLido.count; i++)
        {
            //criando instancia da entidade 
            // adicionando os dados nela;

            ++count;
            context = AddToContext(context, entidade, count, 100, true);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (context != null)
        context.Dispose();
    }

    scope.Complete();
    }
```

E uma função que recria o contexto depois de tantas adições no contexto:

```
private Contexto AddToContext<Entity>(Contexto context,
Entity entity, int count, int commitCount, bool recreateContext) where Entity : class
{
    context.Set<Entity>().Add(entity);

    if (count % commitCount == 0)
    {
        //erro acontece aqui
        context.SaveChanges();

        if (recreateContext)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            context = new Contexto();
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        }
    }

   return context;
}
```

Como posso fazer essa inserção funcionar ou assim não irá funcionar? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Por curiosidade, qual seria, em média, o tamanho do `textoLido`?

Comment: 15 mil linhas, 9 colunas, 135 mil "registros".

Comment: Já tentou colocar alguns USING aí no seu código?

Comment: lol por que diz isso? resolvi esse problema usando o bulks insert do entity framework em uma api

Comment: a lentidão na execução e não ta causando isso não? A transação com o banco ta morrendo em algum ponto e acaba descartando esse context. Coloque um sleep pra forçar um atraso entre os SaveChanges ou modifique o pool e timeout de conexão da connection para simular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme dito por comentário, a maneira correta de resolver é usando o [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](http://entityframework-extensions.net/?z=codeplex), que [possui pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6).

Um exemplo de uso seria:

```
using EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions;

private Contexto AddToContext<Entity>(Contexto context, Entity entity, int count, int commitCount) where Entity : class
{
    context.Set<Entity>().BulkInsert(entity);

    if (count % commitCount == 0)
    {
        //erro acontece aqui
        context.SaveChanges();

        // Isto não precisa
        // if (recreateContext)
        // {
        //    context.Dispose();
        //    context = new Contexto();
        //    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        // }
    }

   return context;
}
```