# Parâmetro ignorado no Connection TimeOut do EF 5.0

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

Minha aplicação está apresentando um erro de `TimeOut` quando executo operações que demandam mais tempo de processamento.

Estou usando o `EntityFramework 5.0` e setei o `Connection Timeout=480` para fazer testes, mas me parece que ele está ignorando o parâmetro que define o tempo limite da conexão.

Abaixo está a minha string de conexão:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TesteContext" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TesteModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TesteModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TesteModel.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         provider connection string=&quot;
         data source=192.0.15.1;
         initial catalog=DBTeste_PRD;
         persist security info=True;
         user id=xyz;
         password=XXXXXX;
         Connection Timeout=480;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
         App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se poderia colocar a imagem de erro na sua pergunta?

Comment: Desculpa esqueci qual é a quantidade de alteração e coloque o código também, foi mau esqueci de relatar esses pontos!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tem mais de 100 operações dentro do método. Pois está dentro de uma estrutura "For". Ele executa uma série de registros e da o timeout.
Não entendi qual a necessidade de postar o código aqui, sendo que não esta apresentando erro nas operações, e sim no tempo limite de execução.

Comment: o código é de suma importância, porque, é por ele que está ocorrendo o TimeOut que você perguntou, como vou imaginar o que o código está fazendo se eu não sei como ele foi escrito, e se existir forma melhor de escrever melhor? E se tem alguma coisa passando desapercebida? tudo é referente a um código que não está trazendo o resultado esperado e dando problema na transação de um ORM?, se puder postar talvez tenha solução ou então um novo caminho. Se tem 100 operações em um método, já é motivo de ligar o pisca alerta de qualquer código ...

Comment: cont ... por exemplo tem uma extensão para Entity Framework para gravação em lote: [BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) isso pode resolver essa parte para você quem sabe! mas, fica dificil sem ver o código. Tem até uma resposta sobre isso aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92884/erro-ao-inserir-dados-no-banco-ef-6/148374#148374 ou essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131541/importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-leitura-de-arquivo/131565#131565